# probleme with react js npm run deploy

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with my `reactjs` app after running npm run deploy and open the path 
Getting this error in the console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fd' of undefined
    at Function.useColors (2.fa6ad6b6.chunk.js:22096)
    at createDebug (2.fa6ad6b6.chunk.js:19243)
    at Object.577 (2.fa6ad6b6.chunk.js:21742)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.574dac58.js:50)
    at Object.390 (2.fa6ad6b6.chunk.js:18982)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.574dac58.js:50)
    at Object.1388 (2.fa6ad6b6.chunk.js:67)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.574dac58.js:50)
    at Object.134 (2.fa6ad6b6.chunk.js:20)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.574dac58.js:50)
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: This is an issue with your code. Look for something that's trying to access `fd` in your code and make sure it's not `undefined`... Perhaps your `useColors` function is the issue here

Comment: seems like file description field was missing in object.